# Checking small network in mininet by Opendaylight

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-player, openflow, opendaylight

I have a question about Checking small network by opendaylight

I am not really sure why I can't accress Opendaylight menu which I created from mininet

I am using windows 7 and VMWare player to run mininet and opendaylight(on Ubuntu).

First, i run Ubuntu to run Opendaylight ( I checked that 120.0.0.1:8080 was working)
Second, I run mininet to get IP address.( i will say "192.168.139.128")
Third, based on IP address , it run two putty to run wireshark and building small network

I used **sudo mn --mac --controller=remote, ip=192.168.139.128, port=6633**.

It successfully build small network.  Because i can check all the node infor by command "nodes" and "dump"
[image]

However, when I go back to Ubuntu VM and access Opendaylight by **192.168.139.128:8080** (it is given IP from mininet)

[image]

I am sure really sure why this happen. Is there any possible reasons ?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, if anyone is facing the same issue, change network adapter settings in VMWare to use bridge mode.

From the [official page](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller%3aInstallation#Using_Mininet)

> Important troubleshooting - if you are running VirtualBox on the same
>   host/desktop where the controller is running, and trying to start the
>   virtual network on Mininet VM produces this error: "Unable to contact
>   the remote controller at ...", then the following resolves the
>   problem:
>
> 1. In VirtualBox, go to File-Preferences-Network and make sure you have at least one interface defined as Host-Only. Lets say its name is
>      vboxnet0
> 2. In VirtualBox - Mininet Vm - Settings - Network, check that the adapter is of type Host only , and is connected to the interface from
>      item 1 (vboxnet0)
> 3. On your host where controller and VirtualBox run, do "ifconfig" command to display all network interfaces on the machine.
>
> Search for the interface as in item 1 (vboxnet0 in our example) Take
>   the ip address specified there (most probably 192.168.56.1 - default),
>   and that is the correct remote controller ip address to use when
>   starting a virtual network in mininet vm as stated in the example
>   above (--controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.1) .
>
> 1. If you are still not able to connect, you might want to consider temporarily disabling firewall on the host running the controller (on
>      Linux, for example, iptables -F will do the job)
> 2. Sometimes, the way you start the mininet is a problem, it does not give error, but does not connect to the remote server. Here is a wrong
>      example:
>
>    sudo mn --topo=tree,3 --mac --switch=ovsk --controller=remote,
>      ip=192.168.16.10
>
> Here is the correct example:
>
> sudo mn --topo=tree,3 --mac --switch=ovsk
>   --controller=remote,ip=192.168.16.10
>
> The difference is the "SPACE" between "remote," and "ip".

Answer (score 0):

Start the Opendaylight and install the odl-dlux-core plugin. After that the OpenDaylight UI can be accessed through browser on port 8181. So try `http://localhost:8181/index.html` and you login using username password admin/admin. You should see your topology show up on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you are VMWare player, at IP use this command

sudo mn --mac --controller=remote,--ip=192.168.139.128 --topo tree,5

and refresh your OpenDay Light Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install Gnome on your Mininet/ODL virtual machine.
I am using the latest (Helium) ODL release so the GUI of ODL is at http://localhost:8181/dlux/indexh.html

on Helium, ODL run inside your distribution folder with ./bin/karaf command (also install required modules inside karaf with feature:install

Attached is my screenshot: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B8ZgSA6CMAAzuSf.jpg:large